# SSRS Parent groups repeating creating a "staircase"

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

The information is correct but its in a "staircase" with repeating columns and rows and a lot of excess empty cells. 
(im new to ssrs hopefully this is really basic)

hours are stored in sub-projects, i am trying to get the sum for each project within each department

So i Added two parent groups one for projects(row) and one for departments(col), and hid the hours row since i only want the sum

```
 inputs 
            _______________________
            |_________|__[dept]____|
            |[proj]___|__sum(hours)|
 [hidden]   |_________|__[hours]___|
```

Here's what i got

```
            __________________________________
            |_____|__D1__|__D1__|__D2__|__D2__|
            |__P1_|__10__|______|______|______|
            |__P2_|______|__76__|______|______|
            |__P1_|______|______|__32__|______|
            |__P2_|______|______|______|__48__|
```

Here's what i want

```
            _____________________
            |_____|__D1__|__D2__|
            |__P1_|__10__|__32__|
            |__P2_|__76__|__48__|
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you have now exactly, but you just need a single row group for Project, remove any other row groups.

Comment: That was the problem! i had extra groups i wasn't using anymore. i'm surprised you figured that out, thank you very much!

Comment: I'll add the comment as an answer so you can mark it as answered.This will help others when searching for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have now exactly, but you just need a single row group for Project, remove any other row groups.